# Variation of parameters with inhomogeneous Airy equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, airy-functions

Let $S(\eta)$ be a function that verifies the equation

$$S'''-\eta S' = H (\eta),$$

where $H(\eta)$ is given by
\begin{equation}\label{h_st}
H=\sum_{n=0}^{n=3} \left [ a_n Ai^{(n)} + g_n Gi^{(n)} \right ],
\end{equation}

the function $Gi(\eta)$ is defined as

$$Gi(\eta)=Ai(\eta) \int_{\eta_0}^\eta Bi(\eta)d\eta - Bi (\eta) \int_\infty^\eta Ai(\eta) d\eta$$

and $a_n,g_n$ are given constants. The variable $\eta$ is complex. It is useful to note the set of relations
\begin{equation}\label{recurrence_st}
\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{L}Ai=0, \quad \quad \mathcal{L}{Ai}'=Ai, \quad \mathcal{L}{Ai}''=2 {Ai}', \quad \cdots, \quad \mathcal{L}Ai^{(n)}=n Ai^{(n-1)};\\
&\mathcal{L}Gi=1/\pi, \quad \mathcal{L}{Gi}'=Gi, \quad \mathcal{L}{Gi}''=2 {Gi}', \quad \cdots, \quad \mathcal{L}Gi^{(n)}=n Gi^{(n-1)},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L}=d^2/d\eta^2-\eta$ is the Airy operator.

How could we solve for $S(\eta)$? I have tried variation of parameters but I obtained a very difficult expression and I have been told that the solution has the same form as $H$,

\begin{equation}
S=\sum_{n=0}^{n=3} \left [ \tilde{a}_n Ai^{(n)} + \tilde{g}_n Gi^{(n)} \right ],
\end{equation}

what's the relation between $\tilde{a}_n, \tilde{g}_n$ and $a_n,g_n$?